# Google Maps: Limit Panning

Tags: google-maps, limit, pan

I'm trying to recreate the pan limit behavior as demonstrated here:
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_range.htm

Unfortunately, it's using the API version 2, instead of the current version 3. I'm updating the commands so that they are current, but I think I might have missed something because it's not working:

```js
<html> 
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://meyouand.us/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {

// Generate map
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.76201, -122.4375);
var myOptions = { zoom: 12, center: latlng, panControl: false, zoomControl: true, mapTypeControl: false, streetViewControl: false, scrollwheel: true, draggable: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);

// Limit panning

// The allowed region which the whole map must be within
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(37.684, -122.591);
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(37.836, -122.333);
var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

// Double check boundaries, plot points just in case
var sW = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: southWest, 
    map: map,
    title: "southWest"
});
var nE = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: northEast, 
    map: map,
    title: "northEast"
});

// Add a move listener to restrict the bounds range
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function() { checkBounds(); });


// If the map position is out of range, move it back
function checkBounds() {
  // Perform the check and return if OK
  if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
    return;
  }

  // It's not OK, so find the nearest allowed point and move there
  var C = map.getCenter();
  var X = C.lng();
  var Y = C.lat();

  var AmaxX = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
  var AmaxY = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
  var AminX = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
  var AminY = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

  if (X < AminX) {X = AminX; alert('hi') }
  if (X > AmaxX) {X = AmaxX; alert('hi') }
  if (Y < AminY) {Y = AminY; alert('hi') }
  if (Y > AmaxY) {Y = AmaxY; alert('hi') }
  alert ("Restricting "+Y+" "+X);
  map.setCenter(new LatLng(Y,X));
}

});
</script> 
<body> 

<div id="gmap" style="width: 480px; height: 440px;"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Would someone mind lending another set of eyes to see if I missed something? :D

(There is another up-to-date version 3 code here on StackOverflow called 'How do I limit panning in Google maps API V3?' However that behavior visually "snaps" back rather than simply limiting the movement beyond the boundaries.)

Comment: Try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level

Answer (score 2):

Use example from this post: [Google Maps v3 - limit viewable area and zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level) and change map listener event from `dragend` to `drag`.
I've just tested it and it works as expected.

EDIT: [Example at js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vjdde/)

Comment: This is not zoom safe method.

Answer (score 0):

There is attribute in agm-map named restriction. restriction is **MapRestriction** Type.
you can find the api doc for this attribute [here](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#restriction). 
as said in the doc restriction attribute restricts panning and zooming beyond the limit we define. here is an example.

```
restriction: {
    latLngBounds:{
      north: 85.0, 
      south: -85.0, 
      west: -180.0, 
      east: 180.0
    },
    strictBounds : true
  }
```

I was working with angular. It was easy to pass this object to limit the panning.

Comment: How to include this maps with latitude and longitude? I have defined latitude and longitude instead of `north`... etc. And I have bind the value using `[restriction]="restriction"` it didn't work