# Google Maps Api V3 - Styling countries or cities

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a map, just for selected area, lets say country, and get rid of some of the labels and stuff that are on the map. I found a styles wizard:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html
But my question is, if u can somehow hide smaller cities, or other countries than my selected one?

I know i can hide all cities at once, or that i can hide borders, but i am curious if i can leave main cities visible, and for example gray out other countries than USA or i would have to manually create biggest polygon ever everywhere except USA? o.o

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google Maps API doesn't offer a way to selectively hide labels in an area. You can only remove labels for the whole map in several categories - e.g. using [MapTypeStyle](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeStyle) containing:

```
{
    featureType: "administrative.country",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
    ]
}
```

hides labels with country names.

To hide an area you have to create your own overlay - some polygon or overlay map type.

When you want to show only an area of the map, it might be also a good idea to [limit viewable area of the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level).

Comment: Just for completeness: var styles = [ {
    featureType: "administrative.country",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
        { visibility: "off" }
    ]
}
];

map.setOptions({styles: styles});