# Constraint visible and pann-able area of google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm displaying a custom layer on top of the standard google map (v3). Now the users can pan out of the extents of my custom layer.

Is it possible to constrain the viewable area to a square given by the top-left and bottom right coordinates?

Comment: Sure! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is prevent the user being able to pan the map at all.  Set `draggable:false` in the mapOptions, and perhaps remove the pan control as well - `panControl:false`

Another idea; you could allow the user to drag/pan the map, but then if they move it outwith your bounds, you could call the `panToBounds` function on the map to move it back to where you want it.