# google map limited area not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

[Google Maps v3 - limit viewable area and zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level)

Problem was solved at above link. But I don't use `google.maps.Map` in my project.

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));`

I used GMap2.

`var  map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));`

But this version not working. Any help?

Comment: You are using `GMap2` but tagged as `google-maps-api-3` ?

Comment: The Google Maps API v2 is deprecated and may stop working May 2013.  If this is a new map, you should be using v3.  If you are using v2, search the v2 group for "top left corner" (it is a FAQ over there too).

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look at for implementation help on the Google Maps API v2 should always be [Mike William's v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/).

This page [Part 7 Restricting the range of map zooms and pans.](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm) should apply.

Remember that v2 is deprecated and will potentially stop working 5/19/2013.