# Google Maps Strict Bounds for panning

Tags: google-maps

I am using the example at:

[Google Maps v3 - limit viewable area and zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level)

The problem is I determined the sw and ne points on my custom map, but it seems to only prevents panning based on the center of the map and this allows for panning outside of the strict bounds.

Here is my code:

```
   var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(sw_lat, sw_lon), 
     new google.maps.LatLng(ne_lat, ne_lon)
   );

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function() 
   {
     if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

     // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

     var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

     if (x < minX) x = minX;
     if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
     if (y < minY) y = minY;
     if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a much cleaner solution. It combines the functionality by listneing/panning based on the center point but uses the test of detecting whether a certain set of bounds is within another. Seems to work perfectly for me.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function(){

        var mapBounds = map.getBounds();

        if (imageBounds.contains(mapBounds.getNorthEast()) && imageBounds.contains(mapBounds.getSouthWest()))
        {
            lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
            return;
        }

        map.panTo(lastValidCenter);

    });
```

// Update: + missing semicolon

Comment: What is `imageBounds` here?

Comment: Oh sorry it's not clear. imageBounds is an instance of the google LatLngBounds class. In this case it is the bounds that you want to restrict your panning to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Answer (score -1):

You'd probably have to use the map.getBounds instead of map.getCenter, and see if the edges of that fall outwith the bounds of strictBounds.

This is completely untested, but something like this is how I'd tackle it:

```
   var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(sw_lat, sw_lon), 
     new google.maps.LatLng(ne_lat, ne_lon)
   );

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function()
   {
        var mapBounds = map.getBounds(),
        map_SW_lat = mapBounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
        map_SW_lng = mapBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
        map_NE_lat = mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        map_NE_lng = mapBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
        maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
        maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
        minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

        if (strictBounds.contains(mapBounds.getNorthEast()) && strictBounds.contains(mapBounds.getSouthWest())) 
        {
            return;
        }

        // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds
        if (map_SW_lng < minX) map_SW_lng = minX;
        if (map_SW_lng > maxX) map_SW_lng = maxX;
        if (map_NE_lng < minX) map_NE_lng = minX;
        if (map_NE_lng > maxX) map_NE_lng = maxX;

        if (map_SW_lat < minY) map_SW_lat = minY;
        if (map_SW_lat > maxY) map_SW_lat = maxY;
        if (map_NE_lat < minY) map_NE_lat = minY;
        if (map_NE_lat > maxY) map_NE_lat = maxY;

        map.panToBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(map_SW_lat, map_SW_lng), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(map_NE_lat, map_NE_lng)
        ));
    });
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The cursor gets pinned to the map and I can't stop panning.

Comment: I corrected the code, but it still does very odd things. I can pan left forever and when I pan down it gets jumpy. I will see if I can follow the logic and fix