# setting bounds in gmap on rails using gmap4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am trying to set bounds on my map to only present a certain portion of a city.
My current code is:

```
     var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(42.340, -71.20), 
     new google.maps.LatLng(42.370, -71.0)
   );

var mapOptions = 
{
    maxZoom:19,
    minZoom:15,
};

handler = Gmaps.build('Google', {markers: { maxRandomDistance: null} });
handler.buildMap({ provider: mapOptions, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42.359, -71.090413));
});

   // Listen for the dragend event
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
     if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

     // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

     var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

     if (x < minX) x = minX;
     if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
     if (y < minY) y = minY;
     if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
   });
```

However the bounds does not work at all and the user can go anywhere on the map. Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order of stuff in your script seems really weird, do:

```
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng( 42.340, -71.20 );
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng( 42.370, -71.0 );
var hyderabadBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast );
var mapOptions = 
{
    maxZoom:19,
    minZoom:15,
    bounds: hyderabadBounds
};

handler = Gmaps.build('Google', {markers: { maxRandomDistance: null} });
handler.buildMap({ provider: mapOptions, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42.359, -71.090413));
});
```

Btw, there is no `bounds` option in google maps, [see doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)

Comment: a) the problem is the user can move, the bounds are not working
b) what else seems weird ?

Comment: a) just realized your so called `bounds` options do not exist in google maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

Comment: b) you put `hyderabadBounds` in your options but `hyderabadBounds` is not yet defined

Comment: if you want to go somewhere precise, you'd rather remove `handler.fitMapToBounds();`

Comment: I don't want to go somewhere precise. I want to limit my users to leave a certain area.As in they can only see Boston on the map and if they try to go out of the bounds of boston they won't be able to do so

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level

Comment: what is `map` here? `google.maps.event.addListener(map,`, you have everything you need to solve your issue in my answer, just think now