# How to insert custom variable name to poerform on bounds changed in Biostall Google Maps V3 API?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, codeigniter-3

I have a code inside my controller where it projects the boundary of every place.

**Code:**

```
public function index() {

    //Brgy. Cagangohan Bounds:
    // SW: 7.274053,125.666105
    // NE: 7.2967,125.730692

    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->load->library('googlemaps');
    $config = array();
    $config['center'] = '7.282397, 125.683499';
    $config['zoom'] = 15;
    $config['minzoom'] = 14;
    $config['disableStreetViewControl'] = TRUE;
    $config['map_type'] = 'HYBRID';
    $config['cluster'] = TRUE;
    $config['onboundschanged'] = ""; //How do i insert some variable or function when i perform this code?

    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    $polyline = array(); //cagangohan
    $polyline['strokeColor'] = 'red';
    $polyline['points'] = array('7.292363, 125.667018', '7.291958, 125.671030', '7.292022, 125.673777', '7.291532, 125.675864', '7.292884, 125.676464', '7.292809, 125.677291', '7.292682, 125.680069', '7.292283, 125.682475', '7.291916, 125.684653', '7.290319, 125.685536', '7.290787, 125.688089', '7.292937, 125.689033', '7.294427, 125.689951', '7.296428, 125.691737', '7.295853, 125.692123', '7.295300, 125.692273', '7.293703, 125.694247', '7.294001, 125.694612', '7.294172, 125.697123', '7.291000, 125.698678', '7.289723, 125.697091', '7.287808, 125.695717', '7.285573, 125.691866', '7.284466, 125.690793', '7.282657, 125.689763', '7.279996, 125.688411', '7.278123, 125.686930', '7.277208, 125.686287', '7.276059, 125.685600', '7.274207, 125.683604', '7.274037, 125.683175', '7.275675, 125.678412', '7.275697, 125.673975', '7.280188, 125.674565', '7.280156, 125.672009', '7.286728, 125.674788', '7.287308, 125.673302', '7.288127, 125.669896', '7.287137, 125.669834', '7.287196, 125.665787', '7.288962, 125.666312', '7.288718, 125.667889', '7.290819, 125.667830', '7.291123, 125.668512', '7.289612, 125.668116', '7.289734, 125.668899', '7.290080, 125.668830', '7.290309, 125.669729', '7.290271, 125.670128', '7.290301, 125.670828', '7.291330, 125.670852', '7.291793, 125.666922', '7.291916, 125.666885', '7.292363, 125.667018');
    $polyline['onmouseover'] = '(\'Barangay Cagangohan! \');';
    $this->googlemaps->add_polyline($polyline);

    $polygon2 = array(); //Sunkist
    $polygon2['points'] = array('7.286877, 125.674819', '7.286781, 125.674996', '7.286712, 125.675229', '7.286584, 125.675473', '7.286448, 125.675632', '7.284572, 125.676616', '7.289338, 125.678617', '7.289348, 125.675876', '7.286877, 125.674819');
    $polygon2['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon2['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#f56c1a", strokeWeight: "1"});'
        . ' polygon_0.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Sunkist");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.287914, 125.676631));';
    $polygon2['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon2);

    $polygon3 = array(); //prk Mansanas
    $polygon3['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon3['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#71f11c", strokeWeight: "1"});'
        . ' polygon_1.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Mansanas");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.284218, 125.677605));';
    $polygon3['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon3['points'] = array('7.284455, 125.676637', '7.283266, 125.677008', '7.282947, 125.677163', '7.282439, 125.677734', '7.282319, 125.678131', '7.285091, 125.678577', '7.284876, 125.679395', '7.284804, 125.679400', '7.285275, 125.679408', '7.285959, 125.677292', '7.284455, 125.676637');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon3);

    $polygon4 = array(); //prk lanzones
    $polygon4['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon4['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "blue", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_2.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Lanzones");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.289198, 125.667392));';
    $polygon4['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon4['points'] = array('7.288149, 125.669822', '7.287217, 125.669796', '7.287196, 125.665787', '7.288962, 125.666312', '7.288718, 125.667889', '7.288672, 125.667813', '7.290819, 125.667825', '7.291123, 125.668512', '7.289612, 125.668116', '7.289694, 125.668921', '7.290085, 125.668830', '7.290322, 125.669795', '7.290311, 125.670120', '7.289385, 125.670077', '7.289377, 125.669943', '7.288149, 125.669822');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon4);

    $polygon5 = array(); //prk tambis
    $polygon5['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon5['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#f51a29", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_3.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Tambis");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.288219, 125.674194));';
    $polygon5['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon5['points'] = array('7.288212, 125.669896', '7.287430, 125.673277', '7.286922, 125.674677', '7.289811, 125.675927', '7.290077, 125.675243', '7.289324, 125.674897', '7.289319, 125.673656', '7.289079, 125.673613', '7.289345, 125.669971', '7.288212, 125.669896');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon5);

    $polygon6 = array(); //prk mangosteen
    $polygon6['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon6['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#09d849", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_4.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Mangosteen");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.291752, 125.669172));';
    $polygon6['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon6['points'] = array('7.292363, 125.667018', '7.291916, 125.671186', '7.291389, 125.671178', '7.291330, 125.670852', '7.291793, 125.666922', '7.291916, 125.666885', '7.292363, 125.667018');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon6);

    $polygon7 = array(); //prk macopa
    $polygon7['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon7['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#09d8c2", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_5.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Macopa");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.275576, 125.682390));';
    $polygon7['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon7['points'] = array('7.275314, 125.680040', '7.275203, 125.680053', '7.275123, 125.680233', '7.275059, 125.680520', '7.274934, 125.681021', '7.274578, 125.681947', '7.274365, 125.682403', '7.274221, 125.683519', '7.275065, 125.684253', '7.275768, 125.684945', '7.276890, 125.681727', '7.276012, 125.681249', '7.275690, 125.680903', '7.275519, 125.680488', '7.275373, 125.680252', '7.275304, 125.680040');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon7);

    $polygon8 = array(); //prk chico
    $polygon8['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon8['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#8c0fb5", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_6.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Chico");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.289709, 125.670953));';
    $polygon8['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon8['points'] = array('7.291389, 125.671178', '7.291330, 125.670852', '7.290301, 125.670828', '7.290311, 125.670120', '7.289385, 125.670077', '7.289287, 125.671805', '7.291288, 125.671977', '7.291389, 125.671178');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon8);

    $polygon9 = array(); //prk avocado
    $polygon9['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon9['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#d7154c", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_7.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Avocado");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.291220, 125.677198));';
    $polygon9['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon9['points'] = array('7.289379, 125.676738', '7.289400, 125.675904', '7.292840, 125.677355', '7.292776, 125.678165', '7.289379, 125.676738');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon9);

    $polygon10 = array(); //prk kaimito
    $polygon10['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon10['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#15d7cc", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_8.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Kaimito");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.290199, 125.674387));';
    $polygon10['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon10['points'] = array('7.292817, 125.677185', '7.289811, 125.675927', '7.290077, 125.675243', '7.289324, 125.674897', '7.289319, 125.673656', '7.289079, 125.673613', '7.289287, 125.671805', '7.291288, 125.671977', '7.291389, 125.671178', '7.291916, 125.671186', '7.292022, 125.673777', '7.291532, 125.675864', '7.292884, 125.676464');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon10);

    $polygon11 = array(); //prk pomelo
    $polygon11['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon11['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#fe7f02", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_9.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Pomelo");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.290688, 125.678335));';
    $polygon11['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon11['points'] = array('7.289379, 125.676738', '7.289306, 125.678605', '7.291592, 125.679562', '7.292156, 125.677977', '7.289379, 125.676738');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon11);

    $polygon12 = array(); //prk atis
    $polygon12['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon12['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#fe02c0", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_10.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Atis");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.292284, 125.678979));';
    $polygon12['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon12['points'] = array('7.292778, 125.678237', '7.292510, 125.681394', '7.291156, 125.680874', '7.292177, 125.677985', '7.292778, 125.678237');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon12);

    $polygon13 = array(); //prk rambutan
    $polygon13['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon13['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#fed202", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_11.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Rambutan");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.291618, 125.681738));';
    $polygon13['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon13['points'] = array('7.290847, 125.681829', '7.291209, 125.680984', '7.292446, 125.681448', '7.292241, 125.682438', '7.290858, 125.681834', '7.290847, 125.681829');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon13);

    $polygon14 = array(); //prk melon
    $polygon14['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon14['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#e3fe02", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_12.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Melon");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.291618, 125.683047));';
    $polygon14['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon14['points'] = array('7.292268, 125.682542', '7.290834, 125.681898', '7.290491, 125.682858', '7.291353, 125.682880', '7.291581, 125.684210', '7.291964, 125.684173', '7.292268, 125.682542');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon14);

    $polygon15 = array(); //prk santol
    $polygon15['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon15['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "orange", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_13.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Santol");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.284324, 125.687948));';
    $polygon15['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon15['points'] = array('7.283940, 125.687737', '7.283488, 125.687477', '7.283009, 125.687579', '7.282968, 125.688141', '7.282064, 125.689515', '7.284466, 125.690793', '7.285575, 125.688420', '7.285686, 125.688008', '7.283868, 125.688832');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon15);

    $polygon16 = array(); //prk sereguellas
    $polygon16['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon16['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#d7154c", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_14.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Sereguellas");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.290752, 125.683571));';
    $polygon16['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon16['points'] = array('7.291964, 125.684173', '7.291581, 125.684210', '7.291353, 125.682880', '7.290491, 125.682858', '7.288678, 125.682802', '7.290319, 125.685536', '7.291916, 125.684653');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon16);

    $polygon17 = array(); //prk fish pond
    $polygon17['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon17['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "blue", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_15.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Fish Pond/Sea Wall");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.291752, 125.692046));';
    $polygon17['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon17['points'] = array('7.284466, 125.690793', '7.285613, 125.688408', '7.286145, 125.688161', '7.286486, 125.688241', '7.286693, 125.688944', '7.286534, 125.689127', '7.287410, 125.689317', '7.288368, 125.689048', '7.289226, 125.689035', '7.290507, 125.687975', '7.290787, 125.688089', '7.290319, 125.685536', '7.290787, 125.688089', '7.292937, 125.689033', '7.294427, 125.689951', '7.296428, 125.691737', '7.295853, 125.692123', '7.295300, 125.692273', '7.293703, 125.694247', '7.294001, 125.694612', '7.294172, 125.697123', '7.291000, 125.698678', '7.289723, 125.697091', '7.287808, 125.695717', '7.285573, 125.691866', '7.284466, 125.690793', '7.282657, 125.689763', '7.279996, 125.688411');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon17);

    $polygon18 = array(); //prk ubas
    $polygon18['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon18['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#d7154c", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_16.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Ubas");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.286963, 125.678549));';
    $polygon18['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon18['points'] = array('7.289310, 125.678681', '7.289278, 125.679735', '7.287565, 125.680247', '7.285363, 125.679422', '7.285275, 125.679408', '7.285959, 125.677292', '7.289310, 125.678681');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon18);

    $polygon19 = array(); //prk bayabas
    $polygon19['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon19['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "violet", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_17.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Bayabas");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.289901, 125.681103));';
    $polygon19['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon19['points'] = array('7.289095, 125.681504', '7.288678, 125.682802', '7.290491, 125.682858', '7.291156, 125.680874', '7.289278, 125.679735', '7.287565, 125.680247', '7.287558, 125.681054');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon19);

    $polygon20 = array(); //prk kasoy
    $polygon20['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon20['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#15d7cc", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_18.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Kasoy");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.290603, 125.679730));';
    $polygon20['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon20['points'] = array('7.291575, 125.679636', '7.291156, 125.680874', '7.289278, 125.679735', '7.289310, 125.678681');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon20);

    $polygon21 = array(); //prk boongon
    $polygon21['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon21['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#d7154c", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_19.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Boongon");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.281515, 125.685716));';
    $polygon21['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon21['points'] = array('7.284079, 125.683373', '7.284057, 125.684456', '7.282543, 125.684363', '7.282149, 125.689615', '7.279839, 125.688108', '7.278502, 125.687332', '7.280543, 125.683911', '7.281906, 125.684834', '7.282491, 125.684008', '7.281536, 125.683327', '7.284079, 125.683373');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon21);

    $polygon22 = array(); //prk durian
    $polygon22['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon22['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "violet", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_20.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Durian");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.283260, 125.686038));';
    $polygon22['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon22['points'] = array('7.285019, 125.684404', '7.283488, 125.687477', '7.283009, 125.687579', '7.282968, 125.688141', '7.282064, 125.689515', '7.282543, 125.684363');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon22);

    $polygon23 = array(); //prk mangga
    $polygon23['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon23['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "green", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_21.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Mangga");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.279024, 125.678035));';
    $polygon23['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon23['points'] = array('7.286714, 125.674719', '7.286437, 125.675513', '7.284479, 125.676564', '7.282989, 125.676972', '7.282989, 125.676972', '7.281050, 125.679919', '7.283551, 125.681432', '7.280374, 125.680914', '7.279863, 125.681638', '7.281523, 125.682754', '7.280631, 125.683673', '7.278502, 125.687332', '7.275768, 125.684945', '7.276890, 125.681727', '7.276012, 125.681249', '7.275690, 125.680903', '7.275519, 125.680488', '7.275373, 125.680252', '7.275314, 125.680040', '7.275326, 125.679912', '7.275841, 125.674060', '7.280226, 125.674532', '7.280258, 125.672065', '7.286714, 125.674719');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon23);

    $polygon24 = array(); //prk mabolo
    $polygon24['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon24['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#d7154c", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_22.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Mabolo");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.282345, 125.679322));';
    $polygon24['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon24['points'] = array('7.282997, 125.678267', '7.283051, 125.679844', '7.282093, 125.680584', '7.281050, 125.679919', '7.282173, 125.678307', '7.282316, 125.678082', '7.282997, 125.678267');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon24);

    $polygon25 = array(); //prk lomboy
    $polygon25['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon25['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#d7154c", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_23.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Lomboy");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.281238, 125.681768));';
    $polygon25['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon25['points'] = array('7.280374, 125.680914', '7.283551, 125.681432', '7.284051, 125.683406', '7.281327, 125.683264', '7.281523, 125.682754', '7.279863, 125.681638', '7.280342, 125.680914');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon25);

    $polygon26 = array(); //prk Guyabano
    $polygon26['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon26['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "blue", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_24.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Guyabano");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.285218, 125.682240));';
    $polygon26['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon26['points'] = array('7.287669, 125.683073', '7.286084, 125.683127', '7.286009, 125.683953', '7.285073, 125.683975', '7.285019, 125.684404', '7.284057, 125.684456', '7.284051, 125.683406', '7.283551, 125.681432', '7.282093, 125.680584', '7.283051, 125.679844', '7.282997, 125.678267', '7.285091, 125.678577', '7.284876, 125.679395', '7.285275, 125.679408', '7.287565, 125.680247');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon26);

    $polygon27 = array(); //prk marang joesil
    $polygon27['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon27['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#09d8c2", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_25.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Marang Joesil");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.281642, 125.683828));';
    $polygon27['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon27['points'] = array('7.281523, 125.682754', '7.281327, 125.683264', '7.282491, 125.684008', '7.281906, 125.684834', '7.280543, 125.683911');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon27);

    $polygon28 = array(); //prk Marang
    $polygon28['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon28['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "yellow", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_26.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Marang");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.287410, 125.684150));';
    $polygon28['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon28['points'] = array('7.288233, 125.683835', '7.285924, 125.685562', '7.286818, 125.686432', '7.285686, 125.688008', '7.283868, 125.688832', '7.283940, 125.687737', '7.283488, 125.687477', '7.285019, 125.684404', '7.285073, 125.683975', '7.285019, 125.684404', '7.285073, 125.683975', '7.286009, 125.683953', '7.286084, 125.683127', '7.287669, 125.683073');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon28);

    $polygon29 = array(); //prk Nangka
    $polygon29['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon29['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "#71f11c", strokeWeight: "2"});'
        . ' polygon_27.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Purok Nangka");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.289305, 125.686596));';
    $polygon29['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon29['points'] = array('7.290319, 125.685536', '7.290787, 125.688089', '7.290507, 125.687975', '7.289226, 125.689035', '7.288368, 125.689048', '7.287410, 125.689317', '7.286534, 125.689127', '7.286693, 125.688944', '7.286486, 125.688241', '7.286145, 125.688161', '7.285613, 125.688408', '7.285686, 125.688008', '7.286818, 125.686432', '7.285924, 125.685562', '7.288233, 125.683835', '7.287669, 125.683073', '7.287558, 125.681054', '7.289095, 125.681504', '7.288678, 125.682802');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon29);

    $polygon30 = array(); //prk Fish Cage
    $polygon30['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon30['strokeColor'] = 'green';
    $polygon30['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "green", strokeWeight: "2",strokeColor:"green",fillOpacity:"0.1"});'
        . ' polygon_28.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Fish Cage Boundary");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.283721, 125.700513));';
    $polygon30['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon30['points'] = array('7.287623, 125.708676', '7.286325, 125.705243', '7.282643, 125.704921', '7.281089, 125.704513', '7.279897, 125.701616', '7.276321, 125.697969', '7.280833, 125.694128', '7.285239, 125.696209', '7.287495, 125.699406', '7.288049, 125.701659', '7.289603, 125.701359', '7.287623, 125.708676');
    //$polygon30['onmouseover'] = 'alert(\'Fish Boundaries!\' );';
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon30);

    $polyline3 = array(); //prk Fish Sanctuary
    $polyline3['strokeColor'] = 'blue';
    $polyline3['points'] = array('7.279734, 125.707408', '7.264195, 125.707280', '7.265089, 125.719983', '7.280415, 125.718352', '7.279734, 125.707408');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polyline($polyline3);

    $polygon31 = array(); //Fish Sanctuary
    $polygon31['fillColor'] = 'transparent';
    $polygon31['strokeColor'] = 'blue';
    $polygon31['onmouseover'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "blue", strokeWeight: "2",strokeColor:"blue",fillOpacity:"0.1"});'
        . ' polygon_29.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    this.infoWindow.setContent("Fish Sanctuary");
    this.infoWindow.open(map);
    this.infoWindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(7.275995, 125.711585));';
    $polygon31['onmouseout'] = 'this.setOptions({fillColor: "transparent"});'
        . 'this.infoWindow.close();';
    $polygon31['points'] = array('7.279734, 125.707408', '7.264195, 125.707280', '7.265089, 125.719983', '7.280415, 125.718352', '7.279734, 125.707408');
    $this->googlemaps->add_polygon($polygon31);

    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

    $this->load->view('Frontend/map_content', $data);
}
```

I just want to apply some code to my controller i'd gather from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level) to limit viewable area of the map from the last left point/corner of the Red Polygons to the last right point/corner of the Blue Polygon(look at the image) using Biostall Google Maps V3 API. But i have no idea on how to insert those javascript codes to the controller where i implement the Biostall codes:

```
var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
new google.maps.LatLng(7.274053, 125.666105),
new google.maps.LatLng(7.2967, 125.730692));

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {

if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

var c = map.getCenter(),
    x = c.lng(),
    y = c.lat(),
    maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
    maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
    minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
    minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

    if (x < minX) x = minX;
    if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
    if (y < minY) y = minY;
    if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
});
```

**Image Sample on how my map look like:**
[image: My Image]

Any help, suggestions and ideas is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Amstell did you read the title? thats my question...
to elaborate, i want to insert the `var strictBounds` in Biostall Google Maps V3 API using the CodeIgniter Controller as I indicate the content of `var strictBounds` and the google maps `bounds_changed` event listener. And i don't know how to do it. Do you have a idea on how to implement it? It would be so appreciated.

Comment: It's really not helpful to post all of your code and ask us to read through it and discern it.  It's better to create a [MVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you with your question.  Javascript is not my language; I'm merely trying to help you provide a solid question so you will get more responses.  No one wants to read through all of your code.  Try breaking it up into smaller pieces that are manageable and ask a question.

Comment: @Amstell I just update my question content by removing my controller code cuz it seems that those codes are "unneccessary" as you mean, i think and following the [MVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rule.

My point on my question is, how to convert or insert a custom variable name in the Biostall Google Maps V3 API? I tried researching in google and stackoverflow to hopefully saw a answer which is related to my question but i failed.

Comment: @emo_noel10, the Google Maps v3 API is not Biostall's.  All they've done is a library that uses Google's API.  You've not added any code to your question that's using the Biostall library, so I'm not sure why you keep referring to it.  You might want to add your PHP code that's using their library so we have more of an idea what you're doing with it.

Comment: @duncan yeah i know, and about that, i newly edited my question content which contains my controller with Biostall codes cuz I didn't folow [MVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code is too long so i guess i edit again my question.

Comment: @duncan done editing my question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get what i want. Here's what i did(inside the Controller):

```
$config['onboundschanged'] = "
    var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(7.274053,125.666105),
    new google.maps.LatLng(7.2967,125.730692));
        if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

     var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

     if (x < minX) x = minX;
     if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
     if (y < minY) y = minY;
     if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
    ";
```