# MapifyPro - limit viewable area and zoom level

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dictionary

Apologies for the narrow application of this question.

I want to limit viewable area and zoom using the MapifyPro plugin for wordpress just like this user did: [stack-overflow Q&A (6 years ago)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level)

I want to allow displaying only a certain area and disallow the user to slide elsewhere. Also I want to restrict the zoom level - e.g. only between levels 2 and 6.

Is anyone very familiar with the mapify system and know where to edit the custom map options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hunted around the plugin files until I found what looked to be the .js file designating map options.

Turned out to be located in wp-content > plugins > mapifypro-master > assets > js > map-instance.js

After finding this file it was a process of adding the code from [stack overflow Q&A (6 years ago)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level) and changing the variable map to mapify's designation of mpfy_map. (screenshot attached)

[screenshot of map-instance.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8uhq.png)