# Only showing a snippet of a google map API

Tags: html, css, api, google-maps

Is it possible to just show a certain part of the map when using google maps API, I'm attempting to only show an google map image of a shopping mall, and do not want any of the other information on there. Is this possible??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can Zoom Levels property to zoom in.

Comment: Yes ive zoomed it a lot but it still shows a lot more shops round the outskirts. Which I was hoping I could just cut them out. I guess not.

Comment: you could use a clip-path tool like clippy to only show the portion of the map you want to show http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 1):

By using the Style rule of `style=visibility:simplified` You can remove the label text from places, but they'll keep their label icons. A similar question was answered here: [Google Maps v3 - limit viewable area and zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818016/google-maps-v3-limit-viewable-area-and-zoom-level)