# how to set google map bounds to show all of earth

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know how to set the bounds such that the map will show all of earth without duplicating continents?  I've been beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out.  Thank....

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, several people were asking about this (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125065/how-do-i-limit-panning-in-google-maps-api-v3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983500/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-set-same-boundaries-for-panning-whatever-the-zoom-le)) but I've never seen an answer. There are 2 subproblems which are both unsolved:

- how to limit panning to some area
- how to disable "repeating" the earth

You are probably concerned more by the second point. But I don't think this is reasonable to do. Imagine you live somewhere at the longitude 180 :-) - say you are at E179.99 then for panning few meters to east (or left) you would have to pan to the west through the whole world :-) The earth is round so I see it as a clear reason why google made it so...