# Google Maps v3 ImageMapType Prevent Wrapping

Tags: google-maps, scroll

I am trying to replicate the behavior seen at:

http://forevermore.net/articles/photo-zoom/

It allows panning and zooming of a photo, but it limits the panning to the bounds of the photo.

The example above using google maps v2 code.

It seems I would have to do the following:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() 
{
    //Get bounds and not allow dragging

});
```

(As seen here: [How do I limit panning in Google maps API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125065/how-do-i-limit-panning-in-google-maps-api-v3))

My problem is:

- Images that will be panned/zoomed are dynamic in size, I want a generic solution (if possible)

If it is not possible to have a generic solution, how do I determine the correct LatLon bounds for an image?

Here is what I have so far:

```
var customTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return "img/earth_tiles/tile-" + zoom + "-" + coord.x + "-" + coord.y + ".jpg";
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 6,
  minZoom: 0,
  name: "Custom Map Type"
};

var customMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(customTypeOptions);


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var myOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 3,
     disableDefaultUI: true,
     zoomControl: true
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('custom', customMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('custom');
});
```

It works fine, it just allows a user to scroll outside of the photo.

Comment: thanks for the code snippet, but can you also post a link to your current working page? hard to trouble shoot without the actual images

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I don't think using Google Maps is really the right approach.  Yes, you can probably hack it into working, but it's not really what the library is meant to do.  (Something about using a hammer to fit a round screw into a triangular hole.)

Additionally, you're subjecting yourself to both Google's [restrictive terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1) (your site **must** be public) and their new [pricing](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_pricing), which means over [25,000](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits) pageviews/day will cost you — and *you're not even using the maps*.

Instead, why not use a library designed for tiled zooming of very large images?  [PanoJS3](http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/) seems to fit the bill.

> PanoJS3 - An interactive JavaScript widget for panning and zooming a panoramic image stitched together dynamically from smaller tiles. This widget can be used for viewing images that are much larger than the available space in the browser viewport. Examples include panoramas, maps or high resolution document scans.
>
> PanoJS3 supports native navigation on most popular platforms:
>
> - PCs (zooming using mouse scroll, same as Google Maps)
> - Macs (2D panning with the mouse scroll or touch panels)
> - Mobile devices with touch interfaces: iOS and Android (supports pintch to zoom and pan gestures)
> - Phones and tablets (scales controls according to the screen size)

Comment: I tried pano js, it doesn't have the ability to put points on a mac that are clickable.

Comment: Yeah, Pano doesn't support that (your question didn't mention that you needed that functionality).  Of course, I'd still be more inclined to add support for clickable points to PanoJS over hacking Google Maps.

Comment: @Chris, you may also try OpenLayers.

Comment: @Tomas - ew.  > 720kB of *minified* JS.  OpenLayers is old, slow, and bloated.  [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) (80kB) is a much better choice for maps.  Either way, I think you miss my point: you're hacking a map library into displaying an image, rather than using a library *designed* to display oversized images.

Comment: thanks @josh for the leaflet link! I "missed" that your point intentionally :) The map functionality is good, since one has the polygon and marker func. that OP needs.

Comment: @josh3736, you are totally missing the point. This is not a hack of Google Map. It is a supported feature in the v3 of the API. In many cases, we still need all the features of Google Map but with a different set of custom made tiles. Trying to create the powerful Google map features in PanoJS (including the navigation and a marker clusters just to mention those two) is insane. In my case, I am not trying and I do not intend to reinvent the wheel. It will spend less money by using Google Map and additional fees than by creating and maintaining a yet another custom map engine.

Answer (score 3):

I got burned by JSFiddle deleting my demo, so I reworked the solution, and am posting the demo below with SO's built-in preview. But JSFiddle is arguably more convenient to edit, so I added the code over there too. [Demo in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utm3pnow/)

The original solution assigns the image's coordinates to +/-50 degrees, but I couldn't reproduce this behavior. This new code uses +/-85 deg. latitude and +/-180 longitude with the default Mercator projection.

I haven't tested the new solution thoroughly, so use it with caution. A particularly nasty bug I found was that using `setCenter()` inside the bounds checking led to a stack overflow. It was solved by replacing it to `panTo()`. My main observations are:

1. First, the solution is hacky. As the latitude increases, so does the space it takes up on the screen. What I do is re-compute the pixel midpoint between the limits of the map bounds when the map is moved, rather than using a geometrical conversion. To make this hack work, the acceptable bounds are dictated by the map's div's height.
2. On the other hand, longitude behaves normally. The trick with longitude is that it repeats, so markers and other items showing up at this limit will be duplicated. I think the way around this problem is to transform the longitude coordinates far from this boundary (as in the original solution transforming longitudes to +/- 50 degrees). Unfortunately I'm unable right now to reproduce this coordinate transformation.

```js
"use strict";

// observations
//
// map does wrap around at longitudes +/-180; however, tile display can be
// manipulated to only show up once.
//
// markers placed around longiudes +/-180 will show up twice. Not sure how to
// prevent this.

var divHeight = document.getElementById("map-canvas").clientHeight;

var TILE_SIZE = 256;

var map;
var allowedBounds;

var bounds;
var sw;
var ne;
var width;
var height;

// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates

function degreesToRadians(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function radiansToDegrees(rad) {
  return rad / (Math.PI / 180);
}

function bound(value, opt_min, opt_max) {
  if (opt_min != null) value = Math.max(value, opt_min);
  if (opt_max != null) value = Math.min(value, opt_max);
  return value;
}

function fromLatLngToPoint(latLng, map) {
  var point = new google.maps.Point(0, 0);
  var origin = new google.maps.Point(TILE_SIZE/2, TILE_SIZE/2);

  var pixelsPerLonDegree_ = TILE_SIZE / 360;
  var pixelsPerLonRadian_ = TILE_SIZE / (2 * Math.PI);

  point.x = origin.x + latLng.lng() * pixelsPerLonDegree_;

  // Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to 89.189. This is
  // about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
  var siny = bound(Math.sin(degreesToRadians(latLng.lat())), -0.9999,
                   0.9999);
  point.y = origin.y + 0.5 * Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) *
    -pixelsPerLonRadian_;
  return point;
}

function fromPointToLatLng(point) {
  // value from 0 to 256
  var pixelOrigin_ = new google.maps.Point(TILE_SIZE / 2,
                                           TILE_SIZE / 2);
  var origin = new google.maps.Point(TILE_SIZE/2, TILE_SIZE/2);

  var pixelsPerLonDegree_ = TILE_SIZE / 360;
  var pixelsPerLonRadian_ = TILE_SIZE / (2 * Math.PI);

  var origin = pixelOrigin_;
  var lng = (point.x - origin.x) / pixelsPerLonDegree_;
  var latRadians = (point.y - origin.y) / -pixelsPerLonRadian_;
  var lat = radiansToDegrees(2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(latRadians)) -
                             Math.PI / 2);
  return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
};

function midpointLat() {
  var tileFactor = 1 << map.getZoom();
  var midpointFromTop = divHeight / tileFactor / 2;
  return fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(0, midpointFromTop)).lat();
}

function addMarker(lat, lng) {
  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  }).setMap(map);
}

function addIcon(lat, lng, url) {
  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    icon: url,
  }).setMap(map);
}

function updateEdge() {
  bounds = map.getBounds();
  
  sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
  ne = bounds.getNorthEast();

  var swLng = sw.lng();
  var swLat = sw.lat();

  var neLng = ne.lng();
  var neLat = ne.lat();
  
  if (swLng > neLng) {
    swLng -= 360;
  } 
  width = neLng - swLng;
  
  var left = Math.min(-180+(width/2),-0.000001);
  var right = Math.max(180-(width/2),0.000001);
  
  var divCenterLat = fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(0, divHeight)).lat();
  var currentZoom = map.getZoom();

  var top = midpointLat();
  var bottom = -midpointLat();
  
  allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(bottom,left),
    new google.maps.LatLng(top,right));

}

function boxIn() {
  if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
    return;
  } else {
    var mapCenter = map.getCenter();
    var X = mapCenter.lng();
    var Y = mapCenter.lat();

    var AmaxX = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
    var AmaxY = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    var AminX = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
    var AminY = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

    if (X < AminX) {
      X = AminX;
    }
    if (X > AmaxX) {
      X = AmaxX;
    }
    if (Y < AminY) {
      Y = AminY;
    }
    if (Y > AmaxY) {
      Y = AmaxY;
    }

    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(Y, X));
  }
}

var moonTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
    var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
    if (!normalizedCoord) {
      return null;
    }
    var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
    return 'http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
      
    '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +  
      (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  maxZoom: 9,
  minZoom: 0,
  radius: 100,
  name: 'Moon'
};

var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(moonTypeOptions);


// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    // ORIGINAL LINE to repeat across x-axis
    // x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;

    // in reality, do not want repeated tiles
    return null;
  }

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 1,
    // streetViewControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('moon');


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    updateEdge();
  });
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    updateEdge();
    boxIn();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    boxIn();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log("map clicked at: " + e.latLng.lat() + "," + e.latLng.lng());
  });

  updateEdge();

  addIcon(0, 0, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|00FF00|000000");

  addIcon(85.1, 179, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=TR|00FF00|000000");

  addIcon(-85.1, -179, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=BL|00FF00|000000");

  addIcon(20.1, 9, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|00FF00|000000");
  addIcon(40.1, 9, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=4|00FF00|000000");
  addIcon(60.1, 9, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=6|00FF00|000000");
  addIcon(80.1, 9, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=8|00FF00|000000");
  addIcon(85.1, 9, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=8|00FF00|000000");
  addIcon(-85.1, 9, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=8|00FF00|000000");

  addIcon(60.1, -179, "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=Y|00FF00|000000");
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image map types</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
      height: 450px;
      width: 450px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <script src="moon.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ORIGINAL 2012 SOLUTION:

I combined the forevermore coordinate system and the [documentation's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes) ImageMapTypes example for the [moon's surface](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image)

Initially, the demo starts at zoom 0, to give an idea of the whole image. After zooming in, panning will be restricted to a rectangle with an aspect ratio defined by the (W)idth and (H)eight textboxes. For this demo, only this ratio `W/H`, or `H/W` is important.

I'm assuming your images will be similar to both of the above, fitting in 256x256 tiles, and having a "black border" around the image. Furthermore, that the image stretches all the way to the tiles' edge on the longer dimension. If not (but at least, the image is centered), the viewable area can be modified in the `latbound` and `lngbound` variables, which correspond to the coordinate grid `(-50,50) x (-50,50)` defined in forevermore.

In the demo, when zoomed in and W > H, the aspect ratio is longer horizontally: the whole width of the lunar surface is visible around the center, and the top/bottom horizontal bars will be blocked. That is, the dark craters on the top and bottom of the full image will not be reachable at zooms above 0. Visualizing an actual image with the black borders, some of the "black region" might still show at zoom 1, whose area decreases as the zoom level increases.

When zoomed in and H > W, the reachable area extends vertically. The dark craters directly above and below the center of the whole surface will be reachable, but the left/right areas, not. In this demo, the aspect ratio is changed by `updateEdge` reading the textboxes; clicking on Set calls `updateEdge`.

Most of the effort in the code was to prevent the movement outside the desired display area. Both the forevermore method and the "How do I limit Panning" were jumpy or caused errors when I tested, so I came up with a modified version of [Range Limiting](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm) that takes into account the current zoom level by measuring the screen width and height:

```
  function updateEdge() {
    imageWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById("imgWidth").value);
    imageHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById("imgHeight").value);
    if(imageWidth > imageHeight) {
      widthPercent = 100;
      heightPercent = imageHeight / imageWidth * 100;
    }
    else {
      heightPercent = 100;
      widthPercent = imageWidth / imageHeight * 100;
    }

    latbound = heightPercent/2.0;
    lngbound = widthPercent/2.0;

    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var width = ne.lng() - sw.lng();
    var height = ne.lat() - sw.lat();

    var bottom = Math.min(-latbound+(height/2),-0.000001);
    var left = Math.min(-lngbound+(width/2),-0.000001);
    var top = Math.max(latbound-(height/2),0.000001);
    var right = Math.max(lngbound-(width/2),0.000001);

    allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(bottom,left),
      new google.maps.LatLng(top,right));
  }


google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    updateEdge();
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    updateEdge();
    boxIn();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    boxIn();
});

function boxIn() {
    if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        var mapCenter = map.getCenter();
        var X = mapCenter.lng();
        var Y = mapCenter.lat();

        var AmaxX = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
        var AmaxY = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
        var AminX = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
        var AminY = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

        if (X < AminX) {
            X = AminX;
        }
        if (X > AmaxX) {
            X = AmaxX;
        }
        if (Y < AminY) {
            Y = AminY;
        }
        if (Y > AmaxY) {
            Y = AmaxY;
        }

        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Y, X));
    }
}
```

The projection and tile fetching code are not significantly changed from their sources.

Comment: the demo is not found 404 :(

Comment: @agungyuliaji I reworked the solution, but it is not the same as the original.