# Does Google Maps KML Layer Contain Maps Center Point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to make sure that my maps center point is with in the boundaries of a kml layer, I've not been able to find much about this but I modified some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125065/how-do-i-limit-panning-in-google-maps-api-v3/3126754#3126754) which seems like it could work, but of course doesn't.

From the Google Maps API I can't tell whether or not .contains() is meant to work with kml layers, or if there is a similar method. Any ideas?

```
// bounds of the desired area
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlLayerURL, {map:map, suppressInfoWindows: true, preserveViewport:true});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    if (kmlLayer.contains(map.getCenter())) {
        alert("withnin kml layer bounds");
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) has a method getDefaultViewport which will give you the default viewport for the overlay (the bounds the map will be centered on to display all the contents.

> getDefaultViewport()  LatLngBounds    Get the default viewport for the layer being displayed.

The returned LatLngBounds has a contains method.

You can't access any of the internal content of the KmlLayer.

Comment: So, if I understand the documentation then, I would use getDefaultViewport() to get the LatLngBounds of the KmlLayer and then use contains on that?

Comment: That was I was trying to say with my answer, yes.  The bounds will be rectangular, but unless you parse the KML with a third party parser (like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)), you can't do much else.

Comment: An idea for a round about way of doing this.
The literature doesn't say, and I can't find anywhere that someone has done this, but if I programmatically trigger a click event at a location, is the KMLlayer click event bypassed or might it trigger it?

Comment: You have to provide all the arguments for the click event, at least last I checked, including those properties that are provided by the KmlLayer when it is clicked, kind of defeats the purpose.  Might be a good feature request...

Comment: Vote for (star) [this enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3006)