# How open a google map in full screen on the same page using Google Maps Api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, my question is - I have a small map on my page and I want  open this map in a full screen on the same page by pressing a button and close it in the same way. I think it can be done by removing div styles when you press the button but I didn't succeed, may be this is a wrong way? I understand that is a simple question but my google skills aren't well developed and I just don't know how to ask this question properly, so I'm asking here.

My code is simply generated by [GoogleMapsTileCutter](https://github.com/bramus/photoshop-google-maps-tile-cutter/) plus I've added some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125065/how-do-i-limit-panning-in-google-maps-api-v3) for limit panning. This is all code that I have done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
    <title>PS_Bramus.GoogleMapsTileCutter</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            color: #CCC;
            background: #EFEFEF;
        }
        span.loading {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            font: 300 italic 72px/400px "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"><span class="loading">loading tiles...</span></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>


        /*
         * = PS_Bramus.GoogleMapsTileCutter Config
         * ----------------
         */

            var repeatOnXAxis = false; // Do we need to repeat the image on the X-axis? Most likely you'll want to set this to false



        /*
         * Helper function which normalizes the coords so that tiles can repeat across the X-axis (horizontally) like the standard Google map tiles.
         * ----------------
         */

            function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
                if (!repeatOnXAxis) return coord;

                var y = coord.y;
                var x = coord.x;

                // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
                // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
                var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

                // don't repeat across Y-axis (vertically)
                if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
                    return null;
                }

                // repeat across X-axis
                if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
                    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
                }

                return {
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                };

            }


        /*
         * Main Core
         * ----------------
         */

            window.onload = function() {

                // Define our custom map type
                var customMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                        var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
                        if(normalizedCoord && (normalizedCoord.x < Math.pow(2, zoom)) && (normalizedCoord.x > -1) && (normalizedCoord.y < Math.pow(2, zoom)) && (normalizedCoord.y > -1)) {
                            return zoom + '_' + normalizedCoord.x + '_' + normalizedCoord.y + '.jpg';
                        } else {
                            return 'empty.jpg';
                        }
                    },
                    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                    maxZoom: 5,
                    name: 'PS_Bramus.GoogleMapsTileCutter'
                });

                // Basic options for our map
                var myOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 3,
                    minZoom: 3,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        mapTypeIds: ["custom"]
                    }
                };

                // Init the map and hook our custom map type to it
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
                map.mapTypes.set('custom', customMapType);
                map.setMapTypeId('custom');

                // bounds of the desired area
                var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                     new google.maps.LatLng(-47,-95.61), 
                     new google.maps.LatLng(47,95.61)
                );
                var lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
                    if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
                        // still within valid bounds, so save the last valid position
                        lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
                        return; 
                    }

                    // not valid anymore => return to last valid position
                    map.panTo(lastValidCenter);
                });

            }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Give some code you've done so far ?

Comment: Added some code that I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a matter of simply resizing your map div, then the following JavaScript should lead you in the right direction:

```
function resizeMap() {
    var myMap = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    myMap.style.height = 100%;
    myMap.style.width = 100%;
}
```

Note that the percentages are only relative to ancestor elements of your map div.

Then you'd map your buttons onclick to the resizeMap() function and you're set!

If you wanted a jQuery approach, this is what the above code could look like:

```
function resizeMap() {
    $("#map-canvas").css({height: 100%, width: 100%});
}
```

To revert the map back to its original width and height, you could first check if the width and height are set to 100%, then resize, but a more elegant solution would be to use a class instead of inline styles, which could resemble the following:

```
function resizeMap() {
    var myMap = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    myMap.classList.toggle("fullscreen");
}
```

Then in your css you can have:

```
.fullscreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Clicking the button would just toggle between turning the class on and off.

Comment: Ok, but how the button should look like because <button onclick="resizeMap()">fullscreen</button> doesn't work, I think may be it's because I have installed the styles of map-canvas wrong?

Comment: In the code that you've just provided, we can see that your map div doesn't have an ID of "map-canvas", but rather just "map".

Comment: And the last question is - how provide loading of a map in a hidden form? I'm asking because your example provides loading of a map in a full screen mode and only after that I can toggle the map view using the button, and also because I've tried to provide loading of a map in hidden form using css styles but the map after that  looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/Yfn0MV2.png). I have no idea why a part of the google tiles not loaded, can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Like this, the answers above do not work.

```
var mapOptions = {
       center: myCenter,
       zoom: 9,
       fullscreenControl: true
};
```