# Update bounds based on zoom level for Google Maps API - Revised

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a custom map and setting bounds to the edge of it, but when the zoom level is changed the bounds don't seem to adhere to those edges.  I have tried the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125065/how-do-i-limit-panning-in-google-maps-api-v3) but they seem to have the same issue.

You can see the same issue with this fiddle from @koen http://jsfiddle.net/koenpunt/n7h6t/, just pan to an edge and then zoom in a few times, the map will start to be cut off at the edges.

Here is my code:

```
var map;
window.onload = function() {

    // Define our custom map type
    var customMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
            if(normalizedCoord && (normalizedCoord.x < Math.pow(2, zoom)) && (normalizedCoord.x > -1) && (normalizedCoord.y < Math.pow(2, zoom)) && (normalizedCoord.y > -1)) {
                return zoom + '_' + normalizedCoord.x + '_' + normalizedCoord.y + '.jpg';
            } else {
                return 'empty.jpg';
            }
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        maxZoom: 4,
        name: 'Title'
    });

    // Basic options for our map
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 2,
        minZoom: 2,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ["custom"]
        }
    };

    // Init the map and hook our custom map type to it
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('custom', customMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('custom');


    // bounds of the desired area
    var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-75.716, -90),
      new google.maps.LatLng(75.716, 90)
    );
    var boundLimits = {
        maxLat : allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        maxLng : allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
        minLat : allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
        minLng : allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng()
    };

    var lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
    var newLat, newLng;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
        center = map.getCenter();
        if (allowedBounds.contains(center)) {
            // still within valid bounds, so save the last valid position
            lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
            return;
        }
        newLat = lastValidCenter.lat();
        newLng = lastValidCenter.lng();
        if(center.lng() > boundLimits.minLng && center.lng() < boundLimits.maxLng){
            newLng = center.lng();
        }
        if(center.lat() > boundLimits.minLat && center.lat() < boundLimits.maxLat){
            newLat = center.lat();
        }
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng));
    });

    //alert(map.getCenter());
}
function getBoundsM(){
    alert(map.getBounds());
}
```

**Edit**: What I ended up doing was resizing the map smaller and added more background around the original map.  This gave the impression that there was not a need to pan beyond the bounds of the searchable area.  More of a 'smoke and mirrors' thing but it worked for my needs.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the zoom level is changed the bounds don't seem to adhere to those edges"?

Comment: @geocodezip What I mean is that when you initially set the LatLong bounds to limit panning up, down, left or right, once you increase the zoom of the map those bounds are no longer accurate and need to be reset, but not sure  by how much or what that equation would be. Make sense?

Comment: I still don't follow.  The bounds are real physical locations, you want to change that when the user zooms in?

Comment: Take a look at the jsfiddle I provided, notice how much water is visible around the map at the initial zoom level, then zoom the map and notice that the water gets cut off as you increase the zoom level - I am trying to prevent this and be able to keep the same bounding area.

Comment: when you say "increase the zoom level" do you mean zoom in (increasing zoom value) or zoom out (decreasing zoom value)?

Comment: @geocodezip yeah I mean zoom in (increase the zoom value), I guess I meant to say value rather than level.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47799/discussion-between-whodeee-and-geocodezip)

Comment: I'd be interested in an answer to this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script  forces the map's *center* to stay within a lat/lon boundary. It depends on the zoom level how much of the map *around* the center you see. If for a given zoom level the map spans 1000 km in longitude, the eastern-most point you're able to see is `allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng() + 500 km`. If you zoom in and the spanned region reduces to 500 km, the eastern-most point becomes `allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng() + 250 km` and so forth.

You seem to want to limit what a user is able to see, i.e. the locations of the map's boundary instead of its center. For this, you'll have to check whether `map.getBounds().getNorthEast()` and `map.getBounds().getSouthWest()` are within the allowed bounds.

Here is an updated JsFiddle which does that. Note that you can still zoom out to an area which is larger than the `allowedBounds`, but won't be able to move on that zoom level anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya7ju/2/

Comment: wow, thanks for the clarification and easy fix/adjustment.  I guess I was looking at it for too long to not see that solution - bounty awarded

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using fitBounds and panToBounds instead of forcing a maximum boundary?

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(41.93707, -88.00018));
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(38.67033, -89.98455));
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(41.68259, -87.64164));
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(41.75036, -87.66525));

setTimeout(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map.GMap, 'resize');
    map.GMap.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.GMap.panToBounds(bounds);
}, 150);
```

You can view this in action on our web site. Note that we are also using marker clustering.
[www.Autoquoter.com Offices](http://www.autoquoter.com/aq/en/Offices)