# Restricting panning to one globe in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map created using the Google Maps API, and I'd like to restrict panning to one globe; by default you can pan continuously east/west, the map repeats endlessly. I'm trying to use [henningj's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242679/henningj) solution posted to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125065/how-do-i-limit-panning-in-google-maps-api-v3)

```
var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180)
);
lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function() {
    if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
        lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
        return; 
    }

    map.panTo(lastValidCenter);
});
```

What I have currently allows no panning whatsoever, the call to 'contains' always fails. If I log map.getCenter() it all looks sensible enough, I think(?!):

```
Object { A: 54.683366, F: 25.31663500000002 }
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `allowedBounds` defined incorrectly.  It should be (from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds)):

> LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng, ne?:LatLng)  Constructs a rectangle from the points at its south-west and north-east corners.

This:

```
var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180)
);
```

Should be:

```
var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180),  //sw
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, 180)     //ne
);
```

(negative longitudes are west of positive ones, negative latitudes are south of positive ones)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mr1c1xb3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can  setting a proper Zoom Level  and resticting the min  e max zoom level

```
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.431487, 30.539285),
        zoom: 2,
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZomm:19,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
```