# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Google maps when I try to set bounds

Tags: google-maps

I created a working google map that I am now trying to have auto zoom out so all the points fit.

When I added:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

and

```
bounds.extend(point);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

I then get this error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
J.get
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
J.set
(anonymous function)
Ey.(anonymous function).zoomRange_changed
Zf
```

All my code for creating the map is:

```
function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("getMapMarkers.php", function(data) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");

          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" ;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          bounds.extend(point);
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
      });


    }
```

Comment: take `map.fitBounds(bounds);` out of your loop, you only need to do this once, after all the looping. Not sure that would cause this error though

Comment: I have the same error but just on the jasmine spec. The spec passes though and the actual view works as expected.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I've just run into the same exception, it turned out to be that the longitude passed into "new google.maps.LatLng" was undefined.

Comment: It also happens if the value passed is a string (or probably anything else than a number).

Comment: I had the same Problem when passing a String for new google.maps.LatLng. Remarkeable is the fact, that this didm't occur in FF, only in Chrome.

Comment: This was my problem also. I was using WIPMANIA API to get long/lat, but since i loaded my google map api asynchronous with Ajax loaded content, somehow i had made the mistake of loading WIP after the initiatlizing.

Comment: Even though this post hints into the/a right direction, it is not an answer but a comment. So we get that error when at least one of the parameters of `new google.maps.LatLng(...)` is either **`undefined`** or **`NaN`**.

Answer (score 4):

### Possible scenarios

- Either `map.fitBounds(bounds);` is not receiving latitude/longitude or both.
- The received values of latitude/longitude are not in correct format(NaN).

Comment: In my case, i am using elastic search and bounds.push(latlng); was taking wrong values. In my case, i misspelled the lat and lng. ES was returning lat and lon and i was using lat and lng.

Answer (score 2):

I used google map plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/
I found myself with the same problem, and as Ollie point, I had my json bad formatted.
This was my json

```
mapObj= 
[
      {
         "latitude": 57.797333,
         "longitude": 12.050211,
         "title": "Angered",
         "content": "Representing :)"
      },
      {
         "latitude": 57.696995,
         "longitude": "11.9865",
         "title": "Gothenburg",
         "content": "Swedens second largest city"
      }
 ]
```

Because of that longitude written as a string, I was getting that error.

**SOLVED:** Having all coordinates as numbers.!

To add the map (assuming local json, if not refer to reference link):

```
    $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function() { 
    $.each( mapObj, function(i, marker) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
            'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 
            'bounds': true 
        }).click(function() {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.content }, this);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting map center to a not supported lat/long also produces this error.

Comment: In my case this was indeed the issue

Answer (score 1):

This error also seems to be raised when you set `NaN` as the value of `zoom`.

```js
map.setZoom(null)      // => nothing happens
map.setZoom(undefined) // => nothing happens 
map.setZoom(NaN)       // => error!
```